# Newtype pattern of the combinations of Rc, RefCell and Box

Tags: rust

Because I don't want to type the code like `Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(MyType::new(args...))))` again and again,
I decided to create the newtype `RcRefBox` like below:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct RcRefBox<T>(Rc<RefCell<Box<T>>>);

impl<T> RcRefBox<T> {
    fn new(value: Box<T>) -> RcRefBox<T> {
        RcRefBox(Rc::new(RefCell::new(value)))
    }
}

trait Interface {}

struct A;
impl Interface for A {}

fn main() {
    let iface: RcRefBox<Interface> = RcRefBox::new(Box::new(A));
}
```

The code doesn't compile with the errors below:
(Playpen: http://is.gd/ITiR8Q)

```
<anon>:19:16: 19:35 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Interface` [E0277]
<anon>:19     let iface: RcRefBox<Interface> = RcRefBox::new(Box::new(A));
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:19:16: 19:35 note: `Interface` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
<anon>:19     let iface: RcRefBox<Interface> = RcRefBox::new(Box::new(A));
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:19:38: 19:51 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Interface` [E0277]
<anon>:19     let iface: RcRefBox<Interface> = RcRefBox::new(Box::new(A));
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:19:38: 19:51 note: `Interface` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
<anon>:19     let iface: RcRefBox<Interface> = RcRefBox::new(Box::new(A));
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

How can I fix those errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not so much with your `struct` itself, but with the `trait` you pass.

Trait objects are dynamically sized objects (do not implement `Sized`).

Normally, when you specify the bounds on a generic type (`T` here), you constrain it, however when `Sized` was introduced it was decided that it would be applied *as a default bound* because most generic code deals with `Sized` types and a result `T` alone means `T: Sized`.

There is a special "widening" bound to say "`T` may not be `Sized`": `?Sized`, which you have to apply if you wish to be able to take `trait` objects. Adding it to your code:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct RcRefBox<T: ?Sized>(Rc<RefCell<Box<T>>>);  // ?Sized

impl<T: ?Sized> RcRefBox<T> {                     // ?Sized
    fn new(value: Box<T>) -> RcRefBox<T> {
        RcRefBox(Rc::new(RefCell::new(value)))
    }
}

trait Interface {}

struct A;
impl Interface for A {}

fn main() {
    let iface: RcRefBox<Interface> = RcRefBox::new(Box::new(A));
}
```

makes it work (http://is.gd/pSZKK2).